# Converting a number to a date (DD-MON-YY) in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I'm selecting a series of columns to place in a new table. One of these columns (`EPISTART_RAW`) is a date variable that is currently listed as a raw number, such as `13042015` and `01010216`. What I'd like to do is convert these numbers according to a sensible date format, such as `13-APR-15` and `01-JAN-16`.

I'm working through various examples I'd found online, but struggling.

Comment: Do you mean you want to write a query to select these as dates, or do you want to alter the data in the tables to change from a varchar to a date type?

Comment: What date is 01010216 supposed to represent? Jan 1st 216? October 10th 216? Something else?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you just want `to_date()`:

```
select to_date(EPISTART_RAW, 'DDMMYYYY')
```

If it is actually stored as a number, you need to handle initial zeros, so:

```
select to_date(to_char(EPISTART_RAW, '00000000'), 'DDMMYYYY')
```

Comment: Aha! I was halfway there, at least -- I'd neglected to add 'to_char' to the code. Much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Date value should be within quote:

```
select to_date(to_char('01010216'),'DDMMYYYY') dt from dual
```

Comment: If it's inside `to_char()` then it doesn't need quotes, that's converting a number to a string. (If it has quotes then it's already a string so you don't need to call `to_char()`.... except to format the string with leading zeros as in Gordon's answer, but that isn't what your version is doing.)

Comment: Inside to_char there is no need for quote, especially for this number to date conversion,  quote is must other wise it will not give correct result , Pl check yourself without quote